# How to fetch and show image path from database into file upload control

Tags: asp.net

I have saved images using File upload control in asp.net now i want fetch its path from database and display into file upload control please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You will have to display image in image control using `Server.MapPath("~/SomeDir/image.jpg")`

Comment: can i view that path in file upload control?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want the server file path to appear in the file upload control?  If you think about it, it makes no sense.  The path that comes back would be relevant to the server, not the user so chances are the location would not exist on the users machine.  If you really need to display the server location for any reason just stick it in a label.